# Scala reflection: TypeTag from context bound doesn't match type parameter

Tags: scala, reflection

Let's start with an example code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
class A[T] {
}
def foo[T: TypeTag](a: A[T]) {
  println(typeTag[T])
}
val a = new A[Int]
val b: A[_] = a
foo(a)
foo(b)
```

The output is:

```
TypeTag[Int]
TypeTag[_$1]
```

Well, I have no clue whatsoever what is `TypeTag[_$1]`, but it sure looks fancy. :) Still, I would think foo's expectations of the world are being violated here, as in if foo gets called with an instance of `A[Int]` then it is guaranteed to have the typetag for Int, and not some other obscure typetag. Also, shouldn't typetags be "concrete" in contrast to weektypetags?

Now of course I see that the compiler cannot tell in the second foo call the type parameter of A. So my expectation wasn't that I magically get `typeTag[Int]` as the output of the second call, but rather I was hoping for a compile time error.

Where is my missunderstanding?

*Some futile speculation
One could argue that what's going on is a call to foo with argument type `A[_]`, or, to make it more explicit, the existential type `A[S] forSome { type S }`. An then the typeTag captures the "_" somehow. But this doesn't really make sense, as foo expects `A[T]` for some concrete `T`, and the above existential type is not `A[T]` for any concrete `T`.
Or maybe a call with an argument `A[Any]`? But then why not `TypeTag[Any]`, and even more severely, `A` is not covariant, so this would also be plain wrong.*

Btw, I'm using scala 2.10.

Answer (score 1):

Type tags are created at compile time, and values are not available at compile time. Once you cast an `A[Int]` to the existential type `A[_]`, all information about the type parameter has been lost.

If they were created at run-time, based on values, type erasure would make it impossible to know `A`'s parameter. Even something that is known to be an `A[Int]` at compile-time is at best an `A[Object]` at run-time (unless `A` is `Array`, but let's not go there).

So your speculation is correct, for `foo(b)`, the type parameter is indeed the `_` from the existential `A[_]`, and that anonymous type variable prints as `_$1`.

Comment: I know type tags are generated compile time, and I also know about erasure, that's exactly why I was expecting a compile time error. It's would be fine that a matching type tag cannot be created for b. What does not seem fine to me is that the compiler still tries and generates something that in my opinion violates the signature of foo. To make the problem clear with your solution: what is the value of the type parameter T in the second call to foo? And don't say '_', because there is no such type.

Comment: `_` itself isn't a type, but it is a placeholder that says "there is a type here, but I don't care/don't know what it is". There is a type `_$1` that the compiler is keeping track of however, and the compiler can still give useful information on types containing `_`, e.g. `(_, _)` is distinct from `(S, S) forSome { type S }`.

Comment: OK, let's go with this hypothesis.First of all, would you even say _$1 is a **concrete** type? I can see that the compiler internally has such type aliases or wildcards but this definitely doesn't seem to me as a concrete type, like Int. (And the API doc says TypeTag is always a concrete type unlike WeekTypeTags, but I have to admit the definition of concrete is not clear to me.)

Comment: Second, what't the relationship of `TypeTag[_$1]` and `TypeTag[Int]`? Given all above, I dare say there must be nothing special, as the compiler knows nothing about Int at the point this typetag is created, right? Now the promise is that foo will receive an `A[T]` and a `TypeTag[T]` for the **same** `T`. And as it receives b, which is an instance of `A[Int]` and `A` is invariant, `T` can only be Int. So, the promise is that foo receives and instance of `TypeTag[Int]`. So, we can conlude that `typeTag[$_1]` is an instance of `TypeTag[Int]`. Is this a correct line of thought?

Comment: Yes, it is concrete. The difference has to do with type parameters and abstract type members. Consider `def bar[T](a: A[T]) = foo(a)`. This fails, because `T` is not concrete and therefore a type tag cannot be generated. If `foo` only wanted a `WeakTypeTag` however it would work.

Comment: Your line of thought would be correct except that existential types make the line "And as it receives b, which is an instance of A[Int] and A is invariant, T can only be Int." false. Existential types are evil.